# Using positional parameter ($1,..) in psql

Tags: postgresql, variables, psql, string-interpolation

I often want to copy/paste sql out of my program code and test/debug in psql and it is tedious to have to replace positional arguments with literal values. Is there a good way to convert:

```
select * from users where name=$1 and email=$2;
```

to:

```
select * from users where name='troy' and email='t@me.com';
```

Comment: I am affraid that the only way is to write some script for it.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [psql variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES). Those can be interpolated in SQL code. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION)

> A key feature of psql variables is that you can substitute
> ("interpolate") them into regular SQL statements, as well as the
> arguments of meta-commands. Furthermore, psql provides facilities for
> ensuring that variable values used as SQL literals and identifiers are
> properly quoted. The syntax for interpolating a value without any
> quoting is to prepend the variable name with a colon (`:`).

Note that ([per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES)):

> The name must consist of letters (including non-Latin letters), digits, and underscores.

So you cannot work with ordinal references like `$1`. I assume you copied these code fragments from function bodies, and that's the reason for ordinal references?
Since PostgreSQL 9.2, even SQL functions can reference parameters by name. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTION-ARGUMENTS)

> Arguments of a SQL function can be referenced in the function body using either names or numbers.

PL/pgSQL functions support named parameters in the function body since v8.0.

My preferred naming convention is to prepend function parameters with `_` to avoid naming conflicts. But that's a matter of taste and style.

#### Only half a solution

So, your example could work like this in psql:

```
db=> \set _name 'troy'
db=> \set _email 't@me.com'
db=> select * from users where name=:'_name' and email=:'_email';
```

You still have to prepare query strings ...
Note the quotes in `:'_name'`. That has the same effect as applying `quote_literal()` on the string. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, some good bits in there so I up voted, but still doesn't let one copy/paste sql that uses positional notation to run in console.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a whole lot better than just running the original query, but assuming that your example is only a trivial one and the actual query is a bit more involved, you could create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_users(user_name varchar, email_addr varchar)
  RETURNS SETOF users AS
$BODY$
  select *
  from users
  where
    name = user_name and
    name = email_addr
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

To get the results you would:

```
select * from get_users('troy', 't@me.com')
```

Again with your example, this doesn't help a whole lot, but I've used this with big queries with lots of joins, and it works nicely.