# Create function with SELECT CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, return-type, set-returning-functions

I want create a function with 2 parameters. This is my `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN duration <=  10000000 THEN '00-01 sec'
           WHEN duration <=  40000000 THEN '01-04 sec' 
           WHEN duration <= 100000000 THEN '04-10 sec' 
           WHEN duration <= 300000000 THEN '10-30 sec' 
           WHEN duration <= 600000000 THEN '30-60 sec' 
           ELSE 'more than 60 sec' END AS "Kategorien", 
   COUNT(*) AS Requestcounter
FROM tablename
WHERE starttime BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-08 14:00:00'
GROUP BY
  (CASE WHEN duration <=  10000000 THEN '00-01 sec'
   WHEN duration <=  40000000 THEN '01-04 sec' 
   ELSE 'more than 60 sec' END);
```

Result:

```
 Kategorien | requestcounter
------------+----------------
 00-01 sec  |           2073
 01-04 sec  |              2
(2 rows)
```

I want this result from my function. But I get the error:

> query has no destination for result data

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION requestcounter(mindate timestamptz,maxdate timestamptz) 
RETURNS SETOF integer AS $$ 

BEGIN
SELECT CASE WHEN duration <=  10000000 THEN '00-01 sec'
            WHEN duration <=  40000000 THEN '01-04 sec'  
            ELSE 'more than 60 sec' END AS "Kategorien", 
COUNT(*) AS Requestcounter from tablename where starttime BETWEEN mindate and maxdate
GROUP BY
  (CASE WHEN duration <=  10000000 THEN '00-01 sec' 
        WHEN duration <=  40000000 THEN '01-04 sec'  
        ELSE 'more than 60 sec' END);
Return; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I know that `RETURNS SETOF integer` is not right but I have no idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Travis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35849623/939860) already provided that you need `RETURN QUERY` to actually return the results of a query from a [plpgsql function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html).

But you don't need plpgsql for a simple `SELECT`. Use a [plain SQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend.html) instead. You need to define the return type either way, best use [`RETURNS TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE) like @Travis also provided, but the data types actually returned have to match precisely:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION requestcounter(_mindate timestamptz, _maxdate timestamptz) 
  RETURNS TABLE (kategorien text, requestcounter int) AS
$func$ 
SELECT CASE WHEN duration <= 10000000 THEN '00-01 sec'::text
            WHEN duration <= 40000000 THEN '01-04 sec'
            -- more cases ...
            ELSE 'more than 60 sec' END  -- AS kategorien -- not visible outside function
     , count(*)::int                     -- AS requestcounter
FROM   tablename
WHERE  starttime BETWEEN _mindate AND _maxdate
GROUP  BY 1                              -- simpler with positional reference
ORDER  BY 1                              -- see below   
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;                    -- never quote the language name
```

- `count()` returns `bigint`. If you define the returned column `requestcounter` as `int`, you have to cast: `count(*)::int` (Or return bigint to begin with.)
- In an SQL function you can use a plain `SELECT` to return rows.
- Avoid naming conflicts between parameters and column name. A common convention is to prefix parameters like I did.
- A positional reference in `GROUP BY` is a very convenient syntax shortcut for long expressions in the `SELECT` list. This also makes sure that `GROUP BY` items match `SELECT` items (which is *not* the case in your first query).
- You probably want to add `ORDER BY 1` or you get an arbitrary order. Your demonstrated `text` values *happen* to sort in the right order.

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM requestcounter('2015-01-01 00:00+01', '2015-03-01 00:00+01')
```

Comment: Thx for your help! requestcounter -------------------- ("00-01 sec",2979) ("01-04 sec",2) This is my result - it is possible that it looks like this: Kategorien | requestcounter
 ------------+---------------- 
00-01 sec | 2073 01-04 
sec |  2 ? Best Regards

So that i have 2 columns?

Comment: @cartmanownz: Call your function with `SELECT * FROM ...` to decompose rows.

Comment: Thank you very much again!! I try this one with postgres 9.3.8 - it works, but with 8.4 there is a problem. Do you know why?

Comment: @cartmanownz: SQL functions support parameter names since pg 9.2. More: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25090744/939860

Comment: Thanks again - that menas _mindate / _maxdate will not wirk in postgres 8.4. Right?

What can i do? with I must use the $n notation?

Comment: that mean i write:

FROM   tablename
WHERE  starttime BETWEEN $_mindate AND $_maxdate ?

Have you some tips for performance issue? version 9 has more 
optimized Performance

Comment: @cartmanownz: `FROM tablename WHERE starttime BETWEEN $1 AND $2` If you have a new question, please start a new question. Comments are not the place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to return a table, not a `SETOF INTEGER`.

Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION requestcounter (mindate timestamptz, maxdate timestamptz) RETURNS TABLE (
    Kategorien text,
    requestcounter int
) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT CASE WHEN duration <=  10000000 THEN '00-01 sec'
                WHEN duration <=  40000000 THEN '01-04 sec'  
                ELSE 'more than 60 sec' END AS "Kategorien", 
    COUNT(*) AS Requestcounter from tablename where starttime BETWEEN mindate and maxdate GROUP BY
    (CASE WHEN duration <=  10000000 THEN '00-01 sec' 
    WHEN duration <=  40000000 THEN '01-04 sec'  
    ELSE 'more than 60 sec' END);
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I think the function you wrote is running a select query with nowhere to send the output, then it's returning an empty set of integers. (That's why you're getting that error.)